# How to loop a read excel function for other excel files with multiple sheets?

Tags: r, loops

I have to read many excel files (weather data from different stations) with multiple sheets (yearly weather data from 2008:2021) and then change it into a new format and save it again. I have done it for one station (one excel file) with multiple sheets and edited it as well for my desired format of putting all the yearly data from different sheets into a single data-frame year after the year and finally saved it (the code is as below).

I would like to replicate the same for more than 50 other stations (excel files) as well, but being very new to R, I have not succeeded. I have read about many post mentioning importing multiple excels with multiple sheets but since my code involves some formatting after reading therefore, I could not find a very relevant answer. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)

#Now looping the same for other years:

years <- c(2008:2022)
datasets <- paste("Lashkargah_AT", years, sep = "_")

for (i in 1:length(years)) {
  
  Lashkargah_AT <- read_excel("D:/Chill R Tutorial/ChillR-basic/AllBasin/Lashkargah_AT .xlsx",range = "A7:AK38",.name_repair = tolower, sheet = as.character(years[i]))
  
  colnames(Lashkargah_AT)[1] <- "Day"
  
  jan <-
    data.frame(Month = 1,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[2],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[3],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[4])
  feb <-
    data.frame(Month = 2,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[5],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[6],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[7])
  mar <-
    data.frame(Month = 3,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[8],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[9],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[10])
  apr <-
    data.frame(Month = 4,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[11],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[12],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[13])
  mai <-
    data.frame(Month = 5,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[14],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[15],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[16])
  jun <-
    data.frame(Month = 6,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[17],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[18],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[19])
  jul <-
    data.frame(Month = 7,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[20],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[21],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[22])
  aug <-
    data.frame(Month = 8,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[23],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[24],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[25])
  sep <-
    data.frame(Month = 9,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[26],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[27],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[28])
  okt <-
    data.frame(Month = 10,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[29],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[30],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[31])
  nov <-
    data.frame(Month = 11,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[32],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[33],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[34])
  dez <-
    data.frame(Month = 12,
               Day = Lashkargah_AT[1],
               Tmin = Lashkargah_AT[35],
               Tmax = Lashkargah_AT[36],
               Tmean = Lashkargah_AT[37])
  
  Lashkargah <- rbind(jan,feb,mar,apr,mai,jun,jul,aug,sep,okt,nov,dez)
  
  Lashkargah <- 
    Lashkargah %>% 
    mutate(Year = years[i]) %>% 
    rename(Tmin = min,
           Tmax = max,
           Tmean = avg) 
  
  
  Lashkargah$Date <- as.Date(paste0(Lashkargah$Year,"-",Lashkargah$Month,"-",Lashkargah$Day))
  Lashkargah <- dplyr::filter(Lashkargah, !is.na(Date))
  
  Lashkargah$Prec <- NA 
  
  Lashkargah <- Lashkargah[c(7,6,1,2,3,4,5,8)]#Re ordering the columns
  
  assign(datasets[i],
         Lashkargah)
  
}

Lashkargah <- rbind(Lashkargah_AT_2008,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2009,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2010,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2011,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2012,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2013,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2014,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2015,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2016,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2017,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2018,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2019,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2020,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2021,
                    Lashkargah_AT_2022)
rm(Lashkargah_AT,
   Lashkargah_AT_2008,
   Lashkargah_AT_2009,
   Lashkargah_AT_2010,
   Lashkargah_AT_2011,
   Lashkargah_AT_2012,
   Lashkargah_AT_2013,
   Lashkargah_AT_2014,
   Lashkargah_AT_2015,
   Lashkargah_AT_2016,
   Lashkargah_AT_2017,
   Lashkargah_AT_2018,
   Lashkargah_AT_2019,
   Lashkargah_AT_2020,
   Lashkargah_AT_2021,
   Lashkargah_AT_2022,
   jan,feb,mar,apr,mai,jun,jul,aug,sep,okt,nov,dez,
   years,datasets,
   i)

#dir.create("D:/Chill R Tutorial/ChillR-basic/AllBasin/Lashkargah_AT")
write.csv(Lashkargah,"D:/Chill R Tutorial/ChillR-basic/AllBasin/Lashkargah_AT_Obs.csv")
```

Comment: It sounds like you have completed the main challenge of loading the sheets of a single file and extracting the data the way you want. Are the other files formatted identically? If so, I would think you could apply the same logic as a wraparound to what you have now, where instead of iterating through numeric sheet names, the outer loop would be iterating through file names saved into a vector.

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring for your feedback, yes actually I have already solved it for one station and now I want to replicate this for other stations/files, yes other files are formatted identically. Actually I was a bit confused in the loops, since there is already one loop in my code and I am like a bit confused on how to make another loop for this code which already has a loop. But thanks for the valuable suggestion indeed